# JavaScript parseFloat() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay so my code works fine but when a decimal i.e. 60.1, 60.2, 60.3, etc. is input for #chance it screws up profit and pay.

For example: 60% is input for chance, 1 for bet.  It returns 1.65 for pay and 0.65 for profit.  That's all correct.

But when I put 60.1, it returns 16.5 ( wrong decimal ) and 15.5 for profit.  16.5 seems like an easy fix but Idk how to fix it, but I have no idea why it's returning 15.5 for profit and thought maybe if I fixed pay it would fix the issue with profit.

What's wrong?

Thanks.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        function updateValues() {
            // Grab all the value just incase they're needed.
            var chance = $('#chance').val();
            var bet = $('#bet').val();
            var pay = $('#pay').val();
            var profit = $('#profit').val();

            // Calculate the new payout.
            var remainder = 101 - chance;
            pay = Math.floor((992/parseFloat((chance+0.5))) *100)/100;


            // Calculate the new profit.
            profit = bet*pay-bet;
                            profit = profit.toFixed(6);


            // Set the new input values.
            $('#chance').val(chance);
            $('#bet').val(bet);
            $('#pay').val(pay);
            $('#profit').val(profit);
        }


        parseInt($('#chance').keyup(updateValues));
        parseInt($('#bet').keyup(updateValues));
        parseInt($('#pay').keyup(updateValues));
        parseInt($('#profit').keyup(updateValues));


    });
</script>
```

Comment: WTH is `parseInt($('#…').keyup(updateValues))` supposed to do? You're parsing jQuery wrapper objects but don't use the `NaN` results then.

Comment: Also, "set the new input values" - only two of them changed; two of the lines are useless.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> parseFloat((chance+0.5))
> ```

looks very wrong. `chance` is a string, so the `+` operator will perform string concatenation. When you input `60`, it becomes

```
parseFloat("60"+0.5) === 600.5
```

while when you input `60.1` it is

```
parseFloat("60.1"+0.5) === 60.1
```

You probably wanted

```
(992/(parseFloat(chance)+0.5))*100
// or
(992/parseFloat(chance)+0.5)*100
// or
992/parseFloat(chance)*100+0.5
// or something along these lines
```

Comment: Wrong: http://puu.sh/3paY5.png

Right: http://puu.sh/3paYU.png

Is that helping you understand?

Comment: @Jake: Not really. Please tell me about the maths you are attempting to use.

Comment: Ok so I'm making a gambling site and it's a 2% house edge.  So the pay should return 2 flat if 49 is entered for chance.  2% (51-49).  And when they enter 60, it should give the proper X(multiplier) for what they should be paid out factoring in the house edge.  Except when they enter a decimal it screws everything up.

Comment: pay = Math.floor((9900/(parseFloat(chance)+0.5))*100)/10000;

This works ^.  Thanks everyone.  BUT, how can I make it so they can change pay and it will update chance?  Thanks.

Comment: @Jake: Yeah, your maths was totally screwed up :-) To have different changing fields, you will need a different handler that does the math in reverse

Answer (score 1):

Change `parseFloat((chance+0.5))` into `(parseFloat(chance)+0.5)`.

Actually, I can't see why it's working with `60`, either. `chance`, as a value of a text field, is a string: `"60"`. Strings don't add, they concatenate: `"60" + 0.5` is `"600.5"`, same as `"60" + "0.5"`.

Comment: Didn't fix the problem.  I did that though.

Comment: Well, that's the right thing to do: you got two independent answers saying the very same thing. If it still doesn't work, update the question and show what exactly is happening.

Comment: This is me updating it telling you I still have the same problem as posted in the OP.

Comment: And I'm telling you that your "update" is useless, because there is no way in hell that you can get the same result if you changed what @Bergi and I told you. Run [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zxDYA/) and look at the console - for all three test values, the result is changed. So while you might still have a problem, either you have a *different* problem, or you have applied the change wrong, but in either case you need to update your code, not say "doesn't work".

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function updateValues(){
    var chance = $('#chance').val();
    var bet = $('#bet').val();
    var pay = $('#pay').val();
    var profit = $('#profit').val();
    pay = ((992/Math.floor(+chance+0.5))/10).toFixed(2);
    profit = (bet*pay-bet).toFixed(6);
    $('#chance').val(chance);
    $('#bet').val(bet);
    $('#pay').val(pay);
    $('#profit').val(profit);
  }
  $('#chance').keyup(updateValues);
  $('#bet').keyup(updateValues);
  $('#pay').keyup(updateValues);
  $('#profit').keyup(updateValues);
});
```

Something is wrong with your Math.

Note:

You don't have to use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` to make Strings to Numbers. the `+` symbol in front of your String that is a Number will convert it to a Number.

See http://jsfiddle.net/PHPglue/JQJMD/ for more details.